# Comparing two proportions: Which standard error formula to use and when?

Tags: standard-error, proportion

When comparing 2 proportions, I've seen 2 ways the standard error can be calculated.

The first I've seen is: 
$$
SE = \sqrt{SE_1^2 + SE_2^2}
$$

The second one is: 
$$
SE = \sqrt{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})(\frac{1}{n_1} + \frac{1}{n_2})}
$$

Under what circumstances would I use the first one vs the second one?

What I'm trying to accomplish is calculate the z-score and confidence that $p_2$ is greater than $p_1$.

Edit, here are examples of sites that seem to talk about the same thing but use different SE formulas:

http://www.kean.edu/~fosborne/bstat/06d2pop.html
https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat100/node/57

Comment: Why don't you just do it the Bayesian way and model each probability as, e.g., a Beta distributed belief, and then calculation the probability that one belief is greater than the other?

Comment: Could you explain what are the variables in your equations?

Comment: My p_1 and p_2 are just proportions of people who did something. n_1 and n_2 are the numbers of observations. So if x_1 and x_2 are the number of people who did something out of the n_1 and n_2 observations, respectively, p-hat is (x_1 + x_2)/(n_1 + n_2)

Comment: Since in this context it would seem that "$SE_i^2$" must refer to $\hat p(1-\hat p)/n_i$, the step from the first expression to the second involves the simplest possible algebraic manipulation.  Presumably, then, the $SE_i^2$ refer to some other formula: but what is it?  Is this question really trying to get at the difference between separate and pooled estimates of $p$?

Comment: I think this may be going in the right direction.  If $p_1$ = $p_2$ = $\hat p$ then yes it reduces easily. Is that what is implied? If I'm using $\hat p_1$ and $n_1$ for $SE_1$ and $\hat p_2$ and $n_2$ for $SE_2$, is it possible to prove the 2 expressions are similar?

Comment: I found my answer. It comes down to pooling or unpooling. Some additional literature can be found here: http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=725796 Thanks @whuber for the inspiration.

Answer (score 2):

I found my answer.  It comes down to pooling or unpooling.

You would use $$SE = \sqrt{SE_1^2 + SE_2^2}$$ if you believe the variances are not similar and $$SE = \sqrt{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})(\frac{1}{n_1} + \frac{1}{n_2})}$$ if you believe variances are similar.

Some additional literature can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20171111214327/http://mathforum.org:80/kb/message.jspa?messageID=725796).

Thanks @whuber for the inspiration.